# Serialization of ctypes.structure in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I am trying to work with a Python wrapper using ctypes. Modifying an example given by the manufacturer, I send frames as a ctypes.structure object, which works fine. But this object cannot be serialized, so I cannot setup a queue for a separate process. I tried using pathos based on dill:

```
import ctypes
from pathos.helpers import mp
import time

#Define point structure
class HeliosPoint(ctypes.Structure):
    #_pack_=1
    # projector maximum seems to be uint12
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('y', ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('r', ctypes.c_uint8),
                ('g', ctypes.c_uint8),
                ('b', ctypes.c_uint8),
                ('i', ctypes.c_uint8)]
frameType = HeliosPoint * 1000

def fill_queue_with_frames(Qf):
    while 1:
        frame = frameType()
        Qf.put(frame)

frame_q = mp.Queue(1000)

ProcessB = mp.Process(target=fill_queue_with_frames, args=(frame_q,))
ProcessB.start()
```

Using pathos I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/queues.py", line 237, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/reduction.py", line 54, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1293, in save_type
    StockPickler.save_global(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 922, in save_global
    (obj, module_name, name))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.HeliosPoint_Array_1000'>: it's not found as __main__.HeliosPoint_Array_1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 269, in _getattribute
    obj = getattr(obj, subpath)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'HeliosPoint_Array_1000'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 918, in save_global
    obj2, parent = _getattribute(module, name)
  File "/home/smaug/anaconda3/envs/Laser_p3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 272, in _getattribute
    .format(name, obj))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'HeliosPoint_Array_1000' on <module '__main__' from 'test_queue.py'>
```

Can this be solved? Is there another way to setup two concurrent processes without serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is that you need a name defined that you don't have. Add the following to the module:

```
HeliosPoint_Array_1000 = HeliosPoint * 1000
```

This appears that it might resolve the unpickling error.

Comment: Add the line to the module? Which module?

Comment: `__main__` that is where pickle is looking for it.

Comment: What is this module and where might I find it? I am running this as a standalone script. Sorry if that is a silly question.

Comment: `__main__` *is* your standalone script. Are you running on MacOS or Linux? Running standalone scripts with multiprocessing on windows can cause problems. You will need to add a separate module where you can store these ctype classes.